# google maps: how can I find nearby marks?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a set of data which is the coordinates of friends, I am wondering that does google provide the service that can help me to find the nearby friends(say within 5KM) given a coordinate(longtitude, latitude)?

Or any other alternatives to make the things easier? I just don't want to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: ha sorry to do this again but at least here's the distance from google maps http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GLatLng.distanceFrom don't know about the proximity search... would imagine it has to do it based on a bounds rect or something for local searchs such as on Android devices I'm trying to do some more searching around... also considering your comment now on the other post, it sounds reasonable so you would just then flag it as close or not close and not go through the exact calculation for all points...

Comment: This may be of use but not sure that it's really an answer as you would still need to search for every address somehow against the lat/lng bounds... http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Viewports it's like every other thing is possible, such is programming :)

Comment: will you load all 10,000 markers into the client? if so you could actually use the contains method on the LatLngBounds object along with calculating the extents of 5KM from the marker your searching around, then use the contains method with each of the other markers to see if they're contained in the LatLngBounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think google provide any sort of API that could be used by you for your solution.

The most feasible solution I see is, sending the lat long to server and then calculating the distance between each point for the given lat long pair. And if the friend is within the mentioned radius (say 5 KM ), return the friends info back to client.

You can find information to calculate distance at following link.
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

One thing you can do is, divide the friends data in continents or countries if possible for minimizing the checks at server side.